# gradle sharing properties among different projects which not related

Tags: java, gradle

I am having a file common.gradle which has common properties

```
def custom = [
status: 'SNAPSHOT',
group: 'com.custom.proj',
version: [
    core: '1.2.0.0',
    modle: '1.2.0.0',
    base: '1.2.0.0' 
    ]
]
```

and using it in build.gradle

```
apply from: 'file:///E:/gradle/common.gradle'

task props << {
    println "group" + custom.group
}
```

and when i run gradle props getting below error

> What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':props'.
>   Could not find property 'custom' on task ':props'.
>
> Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`def custom =` declares a local variable, which won't be visible outside `commons.gradle`. Instead, you can declare an *extra property* on the `Project` object:

```
ext.custom = ... // shorthand for `project.ext.custom = ...`
```

The usage will remain the same (e.g. `custom.group`, *not* `ext.custom.group`).

If you want to share `custom` among all build scripts in the same (multi-project) build, it's good enough to apply `commons.gradle` to the root project, as project properties are inherited from parent to child projects.